# Socioeconomic free geodata?

Tags: data-request, germany, social-process, economy

Where can I find free socioeconomic geodata to download for Germany? Any helpful websites tat provide data in shp or tif format?

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in this field but to put in my two cents, here is what my quick research resulted in :

- This [website](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Laender-Regionen/Regionales/_inhalt.html) should help you get started.
- This [report](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Laender-Regionen/Regionales/Publikationen/Downloads/soziooekonomische-grunddaten.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) has various socioeconomic data of Germany.

By scraping and intersecting the data you should be able to generate the desired data. On the other hand, there are these interactive maps (that you can probably scrape), providing different economic data about Germany.

- [Diverse-Karten](https://www.deutschlandatlas.bund.de/DE/Service/Kartensuche/kartensuche_node.html)
- [Mindestlohns](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Arbeit/Verdienste/Mindestloehne/Mindestloehne.html?nn=206232)
- [Steuer-maps](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Staat/Steuern/Hebesaetze.html)